# Vue.js doesn't show in console data from input update - any error

Tags: javascript, vue.js

I have a little issue with my code. I want to display in console new data from update form but isn't working and I don't have any errors.

I have a list of items. When I click edit, I have an modal with current data and it's work fine. Issue comes when I try to display new data

data:

```
data(){

    return {

        advantage:{
            icon: '',
            title: '',
            text: '',
        },
        advantages: [],
        errors: [],
        new_update_advantage: [],
        uri: 'http://127.0.0.1:8000/api/advantages/'
    }

},
```

Template

```
<div class="form-group">
  <label for="icon">Icon</label>
  <input v-model="advantage.icon" type="text" id="icon">
</div>
```

CreatModal2 works fine.

```
createModal2(index){

  this.errors = [];
  $( "#modal2" ).toggle();
  this.new_update_advantage = this.advantages[index];

},
```

Issue comes here:

```
updateTask(){
  console.log("TEST");
  console.log(this.new_update_advantage.icon);

},
```

When I click the button, the console display only "Test" and don't show any errors

Comment: If you change it to `console.log(this.new_update_advantage);` does it show anything?

Comment: do you have 'vue.js dev tools'? It seems like the new_update-advantage.icon property is simply null or an empty string etc.

Comment: @MattOestreich Nothing. Just "TEST".

Comment: @AndrewCastellano Yes, I have. new_update-advantages isn't empty. In my devtools, I have this: 

new_update_advantage:Object
created_at:"2019-06-05 12:49:53"
display:1
icon:"oihoi"
id:46
order:"hoihoih"
text:"oliho"
title:"iholih"
updated_at:"2019-06-05 12:49:53"
uri:"http://127.0.0.1:8000/api/advantages/"

Comment: When I move all consol logs from updateTask to CreateModal2 it's working and in m console I have all data

Comment: Can you post the entire component? Sounds like something may be async??..